# submit with jQuery remote validation

Tags: jquery, validation, plugins

i have one question about jquery remote validation. I have remote php script and it validation part work nice - but for some reason, when I use remote validation i need to press Submit again (two times). I tried with *onkeyup: false* and *onfocusout: false*, but didnt help. When i exit with tab, field is validated and i need to press Submit just once.
Any idea where to look?